# MAUI Blazor App - Run Code On Any Page Load?

Tags: maui, asp.net-blazor, maui-blazor

Is it possible to run a piece of code on every time a page is loaded whether its being navigated to or any other scenario it may be?

Something like overriding OnNavigate method?

Comment: Make a "BasePage" class. Have all your pages inherit from that. Override "OnAppearing" in BasePage.

Answer (score 8):

I thing that you can use also "Loaded" event:

1. Add the line Loaded="Page_Loaded" to your ContentPage XAML, like
   this:

   ```
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        ...
        Loaded="Page_Loaded" 
   >
   ```
2. Add "Page_Loaded" event code to your page code-behind (.cs) file:

   ```
   private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    <Your code here>            
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can override `OnAppearing` method in the `.xaml.cs` code of the page, and add a piece of code specified to `OnAppearing`. `OnAppearing` means that when the page appears, it will be called.

```
public partial class Page : ContentPage
{
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //a piece of code specified
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the answer helpful to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

An option for when you have both your HTML and your C# code in your `.razor` file is overwriting the `OnInitialized` method:

```csharp
@page "/location"

<h1>Page Title</h1>

@if (items == null)
{
    <p>No loadable data</p>
}
@else
{
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <p>@item.Title</p>
    }
}

@code {
    private List<Class> items;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Load items here

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

This approach is not recommended when you do it for multiple pages, in that case use Jianwei's approach.

Comment: Would whoever voted this one down like to explain their reasons?
This is the answer I could most easily relate to.