# Refresh blazorwebview located in other tabs

Tags: .net, maui, maui-blazor

I have a AppShell which contains a Tabbar and multiple tabs. Each tab have its own  blazorwebview.

My question is, how do I refresh other blazorwebview that is on other tab ?

Comment: You mean you want to refresh the blazorwebview when the related tab appear?

Comment: i need to run this method again "protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()". Currently it will load only 1 time.

Comment: yes, refresh the blazorwebview when the tab appear

Comment: You can refer to my answer of this case: [MAUI Blazor App - Run Code On Any Page Load?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73861775/19902734).